# Get exact values of floats in R?

Tags: r, floating-point, unique, floating-accuracy

I want to get all different float values in a sample:

```
unique(c(0.100000000002, 0.100000000003))
```

But this only returns two times `0.1` which are not unique values:

```
[1] 0.1 0.1
```

How can I list the exact values that are saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just R's default printing limit of 7 significant figures. To see the true underlying values:

```
print(unique(c(0.100000000002, 0.100000000003), digits=15)
```

To change the default behaviour, see `?options`; you want something like `options(digits=15)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `sprintf`...

```
x <- unique(c(0.100000000002, 0.100000000003))
sprintf("%.20f", x)
#[1] "0.10000000000200000294" "0.10000000000299999470"
```

From the [**help page**](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sprintf.html) for `sprintf`...

> f
>   Double precision value, in “fixed point” decimal notation of the
>   form "[-]mmm.ddd". The number of decimal places ("d") is specified by
>   the precision: the default is 6; a precision of 0 suppresses the
>   decimal point. Non-finite values are converted to NA, NaN or (perhaps
>   a sign followed by) Inf.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
    options(digits=14)
    unique(c(0.100000000002, 0.100000000003))
```

Comment: This is the same as @HongOoi 's answer and hence duplicated information.